# How do I hide dnssec keys from results when doing 'dig +trace microsoft.com'

Tags: dns, dig, dnssec

Usually when I run dig commands, it hides the [DNSSEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions) keys (the RRSIG, DS, and NSEC records).

Per the [man page for dig](https://man.archlinux.org/man/dig.1), you can use this option to enable/disable DNSSEC validation:

```
+[no]dnssec
```

But when combined with `+trace` it doesn't seem to work.

I just want a `dig +trace` without all the long strings that DNSSEC key validation shows in the results.

Here's what the results looks like:

[image: Output of dig +trace]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find that the manual page specifically says DNSSEC is enabled when +trace is used:

> +dnssec is also set when +trace is set to better emulate the default queries from a nameserver.

So you can't disable it.  You could pass the results through something like `awk '{ if ($4 != "RRSIG" && $4 != "DS") { print; } }'` to get rid of the rows you don't want in the answer.  Note if you're querying non-existent domains you may wish to drop NSEC and NSEC3 too.

(Other tools could be used as well, like `grep -e` but be careful about dropping rows that should be displayed with substrings in them)

Comment: I only had to add one more condition into the awk for NSEC3 records but this was perfect.

awk '{ if ($4 != "RRSIG" && $4 != "DS" && $4 != "NSEC3") { print; } }'

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have misunderstood the manual: `+[no]dnssec` means that the `no` is optional, so you simply add `+nodnssec` to get what you want.

Comment: `dig +trace +nodnssec google.com` definitely does something different for me! `dig -v` is `DiG 9.16.18` FWIW.